# Nginx error on installing vestacp

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssh

I am trying to install vestacp on fresh dedicated server running ubuntu14.04 with nginx installed, however i have tried to remove this using...

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx

sudo apt-get purge nginx

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Now if i try to access IP, i don't see ngnix default page anymore, but when i try following command to install vestacp...

```
bash vst-install.sh
```

I get following error...

```
Following packages are already installed:
nginx

It is highly recommended to remove them before proceeding.
If you want to force installation run this script with -f option:
Example: bash vst-install-ubuntu.sh --force
```

Please help me to resolve this. thanks

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep nginx`?